# R In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to run AUC package on my dataset, but it gives me the wrong like: 
    Warning messages:
    1: In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'

I copied my data and code in here:

```
> pred[820:840,]
        prediction labels
id1300  0.03270514      1
id9049 -0.21458398      0
id3008  0.10395611      0
id956  -0.12109372      0
id6579 -0.05236555      0
id6428  0.05997380      0
id2286 -0.14315984      0
id6170 -0.09689733      0
id3553 -0.22782475      0
id8639  0.20416261      1
id4456  0.12514264      0
id467  -0.05162327      0
id5029 -0.07452525      0
id1421 -0.10254890      0
id4880 -0.12759426      0
id5140 -0.08773456      0
id580  -0.30139796      0
id3332  0.07563819      0
id7930  0.06709688      0
id1319 -0.13681023      0
id7498 -0.14081864      0
> auc(sensitivity(pred$prediction,pred$labels))
[1] NA
Warning messages:
1: In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
2: In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
3: In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

This should not be a difficult problem, might be my dataframe's format is wrong, but I couldn't find out how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the help for `sensitivity` (`help("sensitivity", package = "AUC"`), you can see that the `labels` argument takes ' factor of observed class labels (responses) with the only allowed values {0,1}'.

Modifying your `sensitivity` call to convert `pred$labels` to a factor removes the warnings and results in a number being returned.

```r
library(AUC)
#> AUC 0.3.0
#> Type AUCNews() to see the change log and ?AUC to get an overview.

pred <- read.table(text = "
                   prediction labels
id1300  0.03270514      1
id9049 -0.21458398      0
id3008  0.10395611      0
id956  -0.12109372      0
id6579 -0.05236555      0
id6428  0.05997380      0
id2286 -0.14315984      0
id6170 -0.09689733      0
id3553 -0.22782475      0
id8639  0.20416261      1
id4456  0.12514264      0
id467  -0.05162327      0
id5029 -0.07452525      0
id1421 -0.10254890      0
id4880 -0.12759426      0
id5140 -0.08773456      0
id580  -0.30139796      0
id3332  0.07563819      0
id7930  0.06709688      0
id1319 -0.13681023      0
id7498 -0.14081864      0")


auc(sensitivity(pred$prediction, factor(pred$labels)))
#> [1] 0.8690476
```

Comment: Thank you very much! @Eumenedies